# If A is an non-zero $2\times 2$ invertible matrix with real entries, prove that $A=trace(A)*I-det(A)*A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To prove: $A=trace(A)*I-det(A)*A^{-1}$

I'm guessing we start with the RHS and arrive at the LHS.

Now, $A^{-1}=\dfrac{adjA}{detA}$, so $det(A)*A^{-1}=adjA$ (adjoint of A)

That's the only thing I could do. I have taken random examples and seen that the result is indeed true, but I couldn't prove it. Please help!

P.S. Does this have something to do with eigenvalues? I know that trace of a matrix= sum of its eigenvalues, and determinant=product of eigenvalues, and if eigenvalues of $A$ are $x$ and $y$, then eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are $\frac1x$ and $\frac1y$, but I don't know how to use this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to get too fancy.

$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = (a+d)I - \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$

Comment: question: why is the determinant 1 here?

Comment: its not, it is (ad-bc)... I have multiplied the determinant by the inverse already.

Comment: *facepalm* got this, thanks so much! :)

Comment: Its worth to note that "obvious" generalization of the problem does not hold!

Comment: @ArpitKansal meaning this is not true for nxn matrices?

Comment: Yes,can you see some examples?

Comment: yes, i tried with a 5x5 matrix that didn't yield this result. thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome! For any $n >2$, an easy counter example is $I_n$,the identity matrix!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention about eignvalues...
Indeed for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, the diagonal elements themselves are the eignvalues.
A $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ satisfies
$A^2 - tr(A)A + det|A| = 0$

Simply multiply by $A^{-1}$ and you will see.